# Query That Pulls Duplicate Parts On The Same Order

Tags: mysql

In my system, there should not be the same part# listed on an order more than once. I'm trying to write a query that will pull up any parts that appear on an order more than once. For example:

```
Order# Part QTY
1      A    1
1      A    1
1      B    5
2      A    4
2      B    4
2      C    3
3      A    5
3      B    5
3      B    7
4      A    3
4      B    6
5      A    3
```

So the problems here would be Order # 1 because part A appears more than once, and the same thing with Order# 3 because part B appears more than once. The rest of the orders would be fine. Where would I start if I want to achieve something like this.

Comment: I would start by looking at "GROUP BY" and "HAVING."  The exact syntax varies by platform, but basically you group by what you're looking for (in this case a combination of order # and part #) and then filter by saying "Having count([Whatever it is]) > 1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query literally follows what you are asking.  It aggregates by the combination of order and part, and returns those values when they occur more than once for a given pair.

```
SELECT Order, Part
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Order, Part
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```